# How to open Python Terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python from the Internet.  I have downloaded Python 3.6 and Spyder from Anaconda. Using Windows 10 device. I need to install speech recognition library, using code:

```
sudo pip SpeechRecognition
```

and for that I am not able to use Spyder.It shows a syntax error. **I need to open the python terminal**.

Comment: To install a package, you should use `pip install` or `conda install` since you've had Anaconda installed.

Comment: BTW are you trying to open the Python terminal or Spyder? Neither `pip` nor `conda` commands is executed in Python.

Comment: @ytu that depends on the version of pip

Answer (score 1):

Go in the Start Menu, and look for the "Anaconda3" item, and use the Anaconda Prompt item there to launch a shell session with the environment set up. Then you can type

```
  python
```

at the prompt, and it will start the default Python you've installed for Anaconda

Answer (score 1):

Press `WIN` + `R`, then type `cmd` and press `ENTER`.

Type in the following command and press `ENTER` and the installation will began.

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

If you have a **virtual environment** set up, however, execute `source activate {environemt_name}` before running the above command.

Type `python` and press `ENTER` to open Python Terminal.

Comment: he's using anaconda

Comment: @Schalton I'm using anaconda, too. Conda is compatible with pip.

Comment: Ahh, I've never ONLY had anaconda installed (I've had it with Python too) pip doesn't install to my conda dir - good to know

It's worth noting part of conda's goal seems to be to enforce the use of venvs, pip from the cmd clashes with this goal a bit

Comment: In my experience, if you want pip to install packages into the conda dir, you need to source activate the conda env first.

Comment: How do you use pip to install to a conda venv?

Comment: First, source activate the conda env. Then make sure you have python and pip installed inside the env. Then do your normal pip installs inside the env. All the packages whether installed using pip or conda are all installed inside the env now.

Comment: it shows Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ' " '

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should install in the cmd prompt.

There is an option to install in your IDE (Spyder)

You can run the following:

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "SpeechRecognition"])
```

Comment: It shows attribute error: module pip has no attribute  main